# CSS Layout shifts to Right on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: css

Super weird: For some reason, my site's front page layout (CSS) shifts to the right on a mobile device when it's supposed to be centered? See: http://www.stylerepublicmagazine.com

Does anyone know why this is? I've seen this error on other forums, but no one seems to have a solid fix for it.

Here's the main portion of the stylesheet for my template:

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0, auto;
    margin-top:60px;

}

#socialmedia {   
float:right;

}

   #topbanner {

    margin-left:180px;
    width:990px;


}

#magnavigation {

    position:absolute;
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:150px;

}

#featureslides {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:240px;
    margin-left:190px;

    width:1000px;
}



div.img
{
  padding-top:40px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding-right:62px;
}   


div.imglast
{
  padding-top:40px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:top;

}   


div.img img
{
  display: inline;
  margin: 3px;

}

div.articlename {

padding-top:5px;
font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size:1.4em;

}


div.desc
{
  padding-top:5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
}


#morefeatures {

margin-top:180px;
float:left;
width:685px;
padding-right:15px;
padding-bottom:20px;


}

#adverts {

    width:300px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:180px;



}


.FrontHeading {

    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    }
```

Thanks,
B

Comment: As others have suggested, you're using way too many absolutes and fixed margins. I mean, on my desktop browser, your layout is on the left. It is approximately centered on a 1440x900 resolution, but otherwise you're going to run into trouble. Your main column should have `margin: 0 auto` and all the `position: absolute` properties should be removed.

Comment: Ahhh. So I should remove position: absolute from the #wrapper as well?

Comment: Yup. I'll throw together a quick mock in jsFiddle and post it for you.

Comment: No solutions for you but thought I'd mention there are also layout issues when switching from portrait to landscape on an iPad mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a lot of `margin-left` properties which causes the elements to shift to the right.

---

Before and after removing the margins on the left.

[image: Margin] [image: No margins]

Comment: The largest declaration of margin-left is in #featureslides (190px), how can that be causing the entire layout to shift to the far right on an iPad/iphone?

Comment: `#featureslides` wraps everything on the page below the navigation (all the sub-features (`.img`), `#morefeatures`, and `#adverts`). There's also `margin-left` applied to `#topbanner` (180px) `#magnavigation` (150px).

Comment: I attached a couple screenshots for clarity.

Comment: OH I see! Okay, so how come my #Wrapper isn't wrapping everything? Did I miss a div or something?

Comment: E.g. shouldn't I just be able to remove the left margins, and center the wrapper with margin: 0, auto; ?

Comment: Ideally that would be the best way solution. But as the other answers have pointed out, a few of the elements are absolutely positioned, so they wont be contained by the `#wrapper`. Take a look at those answers as well :)

Comment: Even if I remove absolute positioning, and the left margins, for some reason my #wrapper still isn't "wrapping"? Lol if that makes sense? E.g. #wrapper { margin: 0, auto; isn't centering all of my content the way you'd think? Hence the reason I added absolute positioning and left margins?

Comment: Or here: I've added <div id="Container"> around the entire layout. In my CSS file, I've removed all left margins, and I've added: #Container { margin: 0, auto; } Shouldn't that fix my problem?

Comment: `margin: 0, auto;` is incorrect syntax. You need to remove the comma for it to work. Also, if your wrapper has `100%` width, that means that there's going to be no margin left to distribute! Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bh2C/1/). Edit: Glad you worked it out :)

Answer (score 2):

As some others pointed out, you're simply using too many `position: absolute` properties in your CSS and basically, you've tuned your layout for one resolution (1440 wide). For example, on my resolution of 1920x1080, your layout appears on the left.

You can fix this by removing all `position: absolute` properties and using substitutes. For example, for the main column, you should be using `margin: 0 auto`, which will center it.

I've created an example of a layout you can use, to get an idea of the various types of positioning you'll want to use for your layout. I essentially duplicated the layout (more or less) using different properties that should scale across resolutions and devices.

### [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6gX3/)

**HTML**

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='banner'>
        Your logo
        <div id='social'>FACEBOOK | TWITTER</div>
    </div>
    <div id='slides'><img src='http://placekitten.com/500/200'/></div>
    <div class='news'>News item 1</div>
    <div class='news'>News item 2</div>
    <div class='news'>News item 3</div>
    <div class='news'>News item 4</div>
    <div class='news last'>News item 5</div>
    <div class='blog'><div class='entryimg'><img src='http://placekitten.com/50/50'/></div> Blog entry</div>
    <div class='blog'><div class='entryimg'><img src='http://placekitten.com/50/50'/></div> Blog entry</div>
    <div class='blog'><div class='entryimg'><img src='http://placekitten.com/50/50'/></div> Blog entry</div>
    <div class='blog'><div class='entryimg'><img src='http://placekitten.com/50/50'/></div> Blog entry</div>
    <div style='clear: both'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font: 18px sans-serif;
}
#banner {
    background: #8888ff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#social {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size: 50%;
}
#slides {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.news {
    background: #88ff88;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* IE8- hack */
    zoom: 1; /* IE8- hack */
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.news.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.blog {
    margin-top: 8px;
    clear: both;
}
.blog .entryimg {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**Result**

[image: Result using the above CSS and HTML]

Answer (score 0):

Too much position absolute for the CSS I think.

Change these few CSS for content to center.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

#topbanner {
    margin-left: 180px;
    width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#magnavigation {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#featureslides {
    margin-top: 240px;
    margin-left: 190px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I suggest you to reconstruct your section as it's quite a mess and hard to control from what I saw.

Comment: LOL. Okay, replacing those few with your code totally botched the layout (items were all over the page)...